# SQL Server 2008 : running totals and null records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have several queries that get account balances from our ERP, but there are several issues I am trying to work around and I am curious if there are better ways or if more recent versions of SQL Server have functions to address any of these problems.

- Our ERP generates a balance record only in periods where there is activity associated with the account. The ERP applications and reports summarize values by period but no record is added to the database so custom processes that need a balance by period require a query/view to calculate this info.

  My workaround for this has been to use a global variable to intentionally create duplicates from the `Account` table and the pseudo period table I created, see below
- Our Account Period table dose not contain a period index (I suppose it should be the Row ID however at some point a fiscal period was added incorrectly and the index was thrown out of order. I have been advised by the ERP provider not to update this without a full reimplementation). I created a workaround table for this.

So I have several queries that work around these issues but they run slowly with just a handful of accounts so a full pseudo table for account balances has not been practical with my methods at least.

I have included an example below for calculating the balance by period for accounts that are not summarized to retained earnings annually (assets, liabilities, equity)

```
SELECT 
    ID AS ACCOUNT_ID, ind.Month_Index, ind.Period,
    (SELECT 
         ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN A3.TYPE IN ('e','r') THEN NULL
                         WHEN A3.TYPE = 'a' THEN ISNULL(AB3.DEBIT_AMOUNT, 0) - ISNULL(AB3.CREDIT_AMOUNT, 0) 
                         ELSE ISNULL(AB3.CREDIT_AMOUNT, 0) - ISNULL(AB3.DEBIT_AMOUNT, 0) END), 0)
     FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE AS AB3
     LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNT AS A3 ON AB3.ACCOUNT_ID = A3.ID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN  
         (SELECT YEAR, Month_Num, Month_Index, Period
          FROM UFC_Calander 
          GROUP BY YEAR, Month_Num, Month_Index, Period) AS ind2 ON AB3.ACCT_YEAR = ind2.YEAR AND AB3.ACCT_PERIOD = ind2.Month_Num
     WHERE A.ID = AB3.ACCOUNT_ID 
       AND A3.CURRENCY_ID = '(USA) $' 
       AND ind2.Month_Index <= ind.Month_Index) AS BALANCE_AQL
FROM 
    ACCOUNT AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ACCOUNT_PERIOD AS per ON 'UCC' = per.SITE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ACCOUNT_BALANCE AS AB ON A.ID = AB.ACCOUNT_ID 
                          AND per.ACCT_YEAR = AB.ACCT_YEAR 
                          AND per.ACCT_PERIOD = AB.ACCT_PERIOD 
                          AND AB.CURRENCY_ID = '(USA) $'
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT YEAR, Month_Num, Month_Index, Period
     FROM UFC_Calander 
     GROUP BY YEAR, Month_Num, Month_Index, Period) AS ind ON per.ACCT_YEAR = ind.YEAR AND per.ACCT_PERIOD = ind.Month_Num
WHERE 
    ID IN  ('120-1140-0000', '120-1190-1190', '120-1190-1193', 
            '120-1190-1194', '210-2100-0000', '210-2101-0000') 
GROUP BY 
    ID, ind.Month_Index, ind.Period
ORDER BY 
    ind.Month_Index DESC, ACCOUNT_ID DESC
```

Any suggestions that might improve the performance of this query will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My high level recommendations are the following:

- Avoid using the IN clause.  If possible (assuming the account table isn't too big, create a temporary table for only the columns you need and load that data with the ID's you are working with.)  Then use that in your code above.
- (not a performance thing but more of a slight change).  The ISNULL(SUM... part is only needed due to you having a "A3.TYPE IN ('e', 'r') THEN NULL".  If you had said THEN 0, you could avoid the null check.
- A correlated subquery within the select is okay, but its a multi-part join that is most likely causing it to slow down.  I'm not sure 100% confident on how you can break this apart to be two separate logical grabs of data and then joined back together, but its the best I got with what I'm seeing here.

Comment: Thanks Bob, I appreciate the feedback. I will deffiantly take a look at the temporary table approach and clean up the code you spotted in your second point.

Comment: Out of curiosity, from what I have read l believe that SQL 2010+ had additional annalitical functions added, specifically SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY xxx ORDER BY xxxx).  If I am understanding this correctly then newer versions of SQL server permit running total calculations in linear time where as my approach has been to use a subquery more or less as a recursive method for calculating the total.  An upgrade form 2008 is long overdue in any case but I am curious if I understood this correctly as it  may be additional selling point fot that option.

Comment: Thanks again Bob, the temp table sugestion seems to have given a slight boost.  Im not sure if there are any option regarding the joins though, still looking into it but I will mark as solved.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Dru - so, quick thing I've learned about Windowing functions, they might work for what you're wanting to do. There is a performance problem with windowing functions on large sets of data.  At least that's what I've seen.  It can be tricky to get it to perform well.  Have a good read on this article and it might help.   https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/t-sql-window-functions-and-performance/

Comment: Thanks again Bob.  I will read up and see what I can figure out.